# Elasticsearch match hyphen

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to match word like "1-2", however I am using standard analyzer which ignores "-",

- I cannot use "analyze_wildcard": true
  because it will return tokens like "1", "-", "2", which is not ideal solution.
- I cannot use third party plugin.

I am trying to set customized tokenizer by using regular expression, however none of them works.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to switch off the analyzer of your field, in which you want to match "1-2". Don't forget to use no analyzer on your search query.

Comment: Thanks for your replying. However I do need to use analyzer to match some other texts. Is there anyway to handle this issue without switching off the analyzer?